# How to ensure design-time checking using generics to instantiate objects in a factory?

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following code to return a new object implementing `IValidateParameter`:

```
public static IValidateParameter GetValidator<TClass, TParameterType>(TParameterType objectToValidate)
        where TClass : IValidateParameter
{
        return (TClass) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClass), objectToValidate);
}
```

And, for instance, this concrete implementation:

```
public class DateRangeValidator : IValidateParameter
{
    private readonly DateRange            _dateRange;
    private readonly Predicate<DateTime>  _isNotMinValue    = x => x != DateTime.MinValue;
    private readonly Predicate<DateRange> _startIsBeforeEnd = x => x.Start < x.End;

    public DateRangeValidator(DateRange dateRange)
    {
        _dateRange = dateRange;
    }

    public bool IsValid => _isNotMinValue(_dateRange.Start) &&
                           _isNotMinValue(_dateRange.End)   &&
                           _startIsBeforeEnd(_dateRange);
}
```

Using above code, this will compile and run as desired since the parameter is of type `DateRange`, per the constructor signature.

```
var dateRangeCheck = ServiceFactory.GetValidator<DateRangeValidator, DateRange>(dateRange);
```

However, this shows no errors in VS2017 at design time but will fail since the parameter does not match the constructor signature.

```
var dateRangeCheck = ServiceFactory.GetValidator<DateRangeValidator, bool>(true);
```

How do I modify the generic method to get design-time type checking when the classes implementing `IValidating` all take different type objects as a parameter?

Comment: The IValidatable interface should not be used for validators.

Comment: @hVostt OK I was using my own IValidatable, didn't realize one existed. Will change it, thanks.

Comment: You can not get a static check for constructors that are not called directly.

Comment: A perfect example of validation frameworks https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Comment: Fluent framework looks nice but for security reasons, company won't allow any public code (sigh), so I guess I will live w/out static checks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making your `IValidateParameter` a generic interface, with a type parameter that shows what data is validated?

```
public interface IValidateParameter<in T>
{
    bool IsValid(T value);
}
```

Then your concrete implementation would be something like

```
public class DateRangeValidator : IValidateParameter<DateRange>
{
    private readonly Predicate<DateTime> _isNotMinValue = x => x != DateTime.MinValue;
    private readonly Predicate<DateRange> _startIsBeforeEnd = x => x.Start < x.End;

    public bool IsValid(DateRange dateRange) => 
                            _isNotMinValue(dateRange.Start) &&
                           _isNotMinValue(dateRange.End) &&
                           _startIsBeforeEnd(dateRange);
}
```

Then your service factory would be

```
public class ServiceFactory
{
    public static IValidateParameter<TParameterType> GetValidator<TClass, TParameterType>()
 where TClass : IValidateParameter<TParameterType>
    {
        return (TClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TClass));
    }
}
```

And you would use it like

```
var validator = ServiceFactory.GetValidator<DateRangeValidator, DateRange>();  
var result = validator.IsValid(dateRange);
```

Comment: ironstone13: This works--and answers the question--so will accept as answer. Thank you. I can't help but feel this should be easier, but that's on me to maybe rethink my factory approach and/or dive deeper into language specs.

Comment: @JJJulien, please let me know what you would like to simplify, and maybe I can help. One approach that is used fairly often is that you typically call `IEnumerable<IValidateParameter<TData>> GetValidators<TData>()` by only specifying the type of data you need to check, and getting back a collection of validators, without mentioning a specific class, so your validation invocation has one generic parameter less

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as my biggest concern was not being able to put all the tests into a single list. I will try your suggestion.